# Dummy STS project is missing Default.aspx and Login.aspx

Tags: visual-studio, wif

Has anyone ever run a problem where creating a new STS project in Visual Studio via the "Add STS Reference ..." menu item yields a project that does not contain the necessary Default.aspx and Login.aspx files?  This was working earlier and now I'm baffled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I see what's happening here.  The site I'm adding an STS reference to is this .Web counterpart for a Silverlight applicaiton but it also contains a WCF service.  "Add STS Reference" is getting confused and using the WCF STS template (which doesn't contain Default.aspx and Login.aspx) instead of the ASP.NET STS template.

Comment: Yes - had same problem! - http://nzpcmad.blogspot.co.nz/2011/11/adfs-problem-with-fedutil.html